# Form submit on button click in a multistep form

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, form-submit

I have a form which has a save and continue button. So I want the third click to submit the data. I have written the following code for it. But the submit portion doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var datastring="";

var d1= $( "#Submit3" ).mousedown(function() {
    alert("Event occurred");
    datastring = $("#reg_form").serialize();
    console.log(datastring);
    });

function submit()
{
    $('form').submit(function(){
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reg.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Data sent');
            }
        });
    });
}   
    $.when(d1).done(submit());
    
    
});
```

Comment: Why use `$.when` but not call `submit()` in `mousedown` function?

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work

Comment: no..that submit part doesn't even run

Comment: @KratiChaturvedi do you want to the form to be submited normally? or ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#Submit3" ).on("click", function() {
      alert("Event occurred");
      dataString = $("#reg_form").serialize();
      console.log(dataString);
      submit(dataString);
    });

  function submit(dataString)
  {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "reg.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Data send');
            }
        });
  }   
});
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if that is what you wanted to do.

Comment: They way you declared the function was wrong. You have written the function inside the form submit function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the button type of the third button to "submit" and the type of other two buttons should be "button" just like this.

```
<button type="button">Save</button>
<button type="button">Continue</button>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

So that when you click on the other two buttons form will not be submitted. Only on the click of third button, your form will be submitted. Here is the script to submit the form

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData=$("form").serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log('Data send');
        }
    });
});
```